# list js with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox, listjs

Im using [List js](http://listjs.com/docs/) on html list with checkboxes and trying to populate it with values object  as in :

```
var values = [
  {
    id: 12,
    action: 'a',
...
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    action: 'b',
...
  }
];
```

HTML :

```
<div id="users">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <span class="id"></span>
      <span class="action"></span >
      <input class="required" type="checkbox">Required
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

and initializing as in :

```
new List('users', options, values);
```

How to make it work?

Just to clearify Im missing how to complete values object and how to define option object so that i could init the check state of the checkboxes initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `options` variable and add object `{ name: 'required', attr: 'checked'}` with other property names. Pass the `options` as a parameter to the new list created.

**Update:**

Based on your comment, I don't think it is possible using the list.js, if you are willing to add Jquery to your application, this is a small hack you could incorporate.

Add `$("input[checked='false']").prop('checked', false);` to your code once the list is created.

Note: You wanna add the above line asynchronously, once the entire list is populated, in case you are working with a lot of data.

Demo -

```js
var options = {
  valueNames: ['id', 'action', {
    name: 'required',
    attr: 'checked'
  }],
  item: 'user-item'
};

var values = [{
    id: 12,
    action: 'a',
    required: false
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    action: 'b',
    required: true
  }
];

var userList = new List('user-list', options, values);

//Once the entire list is populated, set all checked='false' checkboxes to unchecked state.
$("input[checked='false']").prop('checked', false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.5.0/list.min.js"></script>

<div id="user-list">
  <ul class="list"></ul>
</div>

<div style="display:none;">
  <!-- A template element is needed when list is empty, TODO: needs a better solution -->
  <li id="user-item">
    <span class="id"></span>
    <span class="action"></span >
    <input class="required" type="checkbox" />Required
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: but how do you initialize the list say with one item checked and second nonchecked at initialization by the values array? in general ofcourse which items are to be checked and which not should be defined by values object somehow but how?